# Does archiving code in my custom class get interrupted when the phone rings?

Tags: ios, persistence, archiving

I have a (model) class which contains an array, and the methods to add and remove elements from this array. It also contains methods to archive and unarchive these elements - it conforms to the NSCoding protocol. All of these methods work fine. Everytime I add or remove an element from the array, I archive the array. Everytime the app loads its main view, I unarchive the array and display the data contained in the elements. Everything works good.

My question is, do I have to worry that the archiving code might get interrupted when the iphone rings, and thus not complete properly? To put it in other words, should I also call the archiving method from the applicationWillResignActive method in the appDelegate? Or indeed should I *only* call the archiving method in applicationWillResignActive, and never when an element is added or subtracted from the array?